# i am getting error of ABC error from rubocop how i can remove it

Tags: ruby, rubocop

```rb
def result_p3(high, low)
    arr_ind = []
    ((1..31).each { |n| arr_ind << n })
    (0..30).each do |i|
      puts " #{arr_ind[i]}" + " #{'+' * high[i].to_i} ".red + "#{high[i].to_i}C "
      puts " #{arr_ind[i]}" + " #{'+' * low[i].to_i} ".blue + "#{low[i].to_i}C "
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

RuboCop is pretty clear about what the problem is: [your method is too large](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/1.22/cops_metrics.html#metricsabcsize). You can:

1. refactor your code so that it fits within your team's coding standards, which is the recommended approach;
2. [update your todo file](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/1.22/configuration.html#automatically-generated-configuration) so you don't see the error until you're ready to fix it; or
3. [disable the cop for this method](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/1.22/configuration.html#disabling-cops-within-source-code), which is something you definitely shouldn't be doing if you don't understand why RuboCop is telling you that your code is not ideal.

RuboCop is a linter and [style guide](https://rubystyle.guide/). It isn't always right, but in this case it is. Your method needs to be refactored, so either do that or postpone fixing it, but definitely treat it as a code smell.

Answer (score 0):

`arr_ind` is redundant, it contains numbers from 1 to 31 in it. For any value of `x`, `arr_ind[x] == x + 1`. Instead of `#{arr_ind[i]}`, you could just `#{i + 1}`. And of course, remove everything related to `arr_ind`.